# Can't find any documentation about some arguments of manim code

Tags: manim

I was just looking at the example gallery of the community version of manim and was looking at [this example](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/examples.html#openingmanim) and I noticed things that I couldn't find anything about what they were called much less how to use them. For example:

```
VGroup(title, basel).arrange(DOWN)
```

or

```
grid_transform_title.move_to(grid_title, UL)
```

I don't know what the .arrange(...) or .move_to(...) things are called and just need something to point me in the right direction to where I can learn more about these.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.arrange()` is a method which `VGroup` inherits from its parent `MObject` and it is described under this object's documentation page:
[`Mobject().arrange()` documentation](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.mobject.Mobject.html?highlight=arrange#manim.mobject.mobject.Mobject.arrange)

`.move_to()` does exactly what it sounds like, it moves an object to a new position. It is explained in the Quickstart and also on `Mobject`'s documentation page:
[`Mobject().move_to()` documentation](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.mobject.Mobject.html?highlight=arrange#manim.mobject.mobject.Mobject.move_to)

The search function on the ManimCE website is actually quite good. Also there is a direct link from every object and method to the underlying source code.